# Business Data Catalog: Application Definition File issue

Tags: 2007, business-data-catalog

I created my BDC application definition file with the help of Application Definition Designer. Before exporting the file, I executed the methods and they are all executing fine without issues. I then exported the file and imported it in my SSP which got imported without issues.

However, when I try to add the Business Data List webpart and tried to browse the business data type, I am unable to get the just imported application file. I tried the same steps with BDC meta man and I am able to view my Business data in SharePoint.

Do I need to do any specific changes before exporting my ADF file while using Application Definition Designer?

Comment: Have you correctly set up security on the entity?

Comment: Yes. First i tried with Windows Authentication, which did not work. I then tried with SQL Authentication. But the same. I am still no able to select the data type in the business data list web part.

Comment: What i ment was, if you had properly configured security for BDC as described in this and underlying documentation http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262207(v=office.12).aspx